# RealityKit Multipeer Session - Object Sync Issue

Tags: swift, arkit, multipeer-connectivity, realitykit

I can’t figure out the common objects of 3D models for multipeer sessions (with their synchronization).

*Design:*
Users of the application can enter a multipeer session, place objects on the stage, while other peers can see these models, their transformations, interact with these objects themselves and place their own - while also maintaining the ability to interact with their objects to other peers of the session.

*Questions I have encountered:*

1. How to publish one instance of a model for one object (now when you publish two copies of each model are obtained - one instance of a model for peer A, which peer B cannot interact with, and one instance of a model for peer B, with which peer A cannot interact).

**UPDATE:**
This issue was resolved by adding in the `session (_ session :, didAdd anchors:)` code block (modeled on WWDC 2019 - 610):

```swift
// Use session identifier to determine creator of the ARAnchor
// Self-placed ARanchor
if anchor.sessionIdentifier == session.identifier {
   // ...
// ARAnchor from another participant
} else {
   // ...
}
```

Now func correctly separates addition of its anchors from those added by other participants.

In addition, when loading, for example, *modelA*, with *peer A*, in order to use this model in a multipeer session, you need to not only load it in `ModelEntity.loadAsync (contentsOf :)` method, but give a unique *multipeer session name* via `ModelEntity.loadAsync (contentsOf :, withName :)` - then at *peer B* in `session (_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor])` you get model name (for example, *modelA*) from name of such ARAnchor (when created on *peer A*, it should be named - for example, *anchor_modelA*), you also load as an asset through `ModelEntity.loadAsync (contentsOf :, withName: "modelA")` - in `contentsOf:` specify the URL of the locally stored model file, after which *modelA* correctly displayed at the *peer B*, and in the placement of the duplicate does not occur.

2. When changing some settings, I get only a wireframe for peer В (AnchorEntity + Collision + Gestures for Entity, where Entity itself with the loaded model is missing) - this option in some sense works, since only one instance gets onto the scene , and peer A (author) can interact with him (peer B cannot), but still this is an unsatisfactory result.

**UPDATE:**
Answer in paragraph 1

3. How to dynamically transfer and obtain Entity rights (when peer B can work with peer A model and vice versa)?

*Scenario:*

1. I tap on the screen to save simd_float4x4 for the future ARAnchor, select the model file from the local file directory, and return.
2. By simd_float4x4 I form ARAnchor:

```swift
    /// Creates and adds in ARSession new ARAnchor.
    /// - Parameter modelName: Name of placed model to form name of ARAnchor.
    func placeAnchor(with modelName: String) {

        defer {
            tempSimd_float4x4 = nil
        }

        guard let worldPosition = tempSimd_float4x4 else { fatalError()}
        let anchor = ARAnchor(name: "\(SettingsApp.anchorARSessionPrefix)\(modelName)", transform: worldPosition)

        arView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
    }
```

3. In method `session (_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor])`, after adding ARAnchor, it is validated by name and function is called

```swift
    /// Adds model to scene of ARView.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - anchor: Anchor for AnchorEntity binding.
    ///   - modelName: Name of added model.
    ///   - modelLocalUrl: URL of  added model.
    /// - Throws: Function can throw exceptions.
    func placeEntity(for anchor: ARAnchor, modelName: String, modelLocalUrl: URL?) throws {

        defer {
            keychainSwift.delete(KeychainSwiftKeys.placingModelURL.rawValue)
        }

        var modelURL: URL?
        if modelLocalUrl == nil {
            if let modelUrlKeychainString = keychainSwift.get(KeychainSwiftKeys.placingModelURL.rawValue),
                let modelUrlKeychainURL = URL(string: modelUrlKeychainString) {
                modelURL = modelUrlKeychainURL
            } else {
                fatalError()
            }
        } else {
            modelURL = modelLocalUrl
        }

        do {

            let modelEntity = try Entity.loadModel(contentsOf: modelURL!, withName: "\(SettingsApp.modelEntityARSessionPrefix)\(String(modelName))")
            modelEntity.name = "\(SettingsApp.modelEntityARSessionPrefix)\(modelName)"
            modelEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)

            let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: anchor)
            anchorEntity.name = "\(SettingsApp.anchorEntityARSessionPrefix)\(modelName)"
            anchorEntity.addChild(modelEntity)

            arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)

            arView.installGestures(for: modelEntity)

            playAnimation(for: modelEntity)

        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Accordingly, when transferring Collaboration Data, peer B calls `session (_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor])`, ARAnchor validates by name and also calls `placeEntity (for anchor :, modelName :, modelLocalUrl :?) throws`.

The multipeer session is configured as shown here:
https://github.com/AddedLayer/multipeer-session

I will accept any help with thanks, thank you in advance for the answers! Have a nice code!